# $x^2 > k \implies |x| > \sqrt{k}$?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, absolute-value

**Is the following true?**

If $k \geq 0$...

$x^2 > k \implies$

$|x| > \sqrt k \implies$

$x > \sqrt k$ or $x < -\sqrt k$

If $k < 0$...

$x^2 > k \implies$

$x^2 \geq 0$

Comment: If $k$ is nonnegative, yes

Comment: @Peter -- OK, let me edit it to regard negative numbers.

Comment: Not necessary. If $k$ is negative , then $x^2>k$ is always true

Comment: @Peter -- But I'd like to make the range as "tight" as possible. So, shouldn't I bound the low end to $0$?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean

Comment: Yeah. If $\sqrt{k} \ge |x| ; k > 0$ then $\sqrt{k}*\sqrt{k} \ge \sqrt{k}|x| \ge |x||x|$ and thats a contradiction.

Comment: @Peter -- $x^2 > 0$ cuts the "slack" (with lack of better terminology) out of $x^2 > k$ (when $k < 0$). Correct?

Comment: @SirJony No, not entirely. $x^2 > k$ allows $x = 0$, while $x^2 > 0$ doesn't.

Comment: If $x^2 \ge 0 > k$ then the k is completely irrelevant and provides no information.  All we can conclude is .... x is real and |x| in non-negative.

Comment: @Arthur -- Good point. I missed the edge case. Can't I just turn $x > 0$ to $x \geq 0$ to fix it? And, as clarification, this is only for $k < 0$.

Comment: @SirJony Do you want a compact notation for the $x$ satisfying the inequality for all real $k$ ?

Comment: @Peter -- What's compact notation?

Comment: A notation valid for negative and non-negative $k$ without distinguishing the cases

Comment: @Peter -- Oh, OK. Well, I'm actually trying to solve a more complicated problem, where I want the answer to be the range of $x$, so I think that wouldn't be appropriate (because when $k$ is negative, the range of $x$ is $[0,\infty)$, which differs when $k$ is positive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just distinguish the cases

If $k$ is nonnegative then $x^2>k$ is true if and only if $x>\sqrt{k}$ or $x<-\sqrt{k}$

If $k$ is negative, then $x^2>k$ is true for all $x\in \mathbb R$

In your case we have the additional restriction $x\ge 0$. Then, we have :

If $k$ is nonnegative, then $x^2>k$ is true if and only if $x>\sqrt{k}$

If $k$ is negative, then $x^2>k$ is true if and only if $x\ge 0$

Comment: @Sir Jony Please check, whether the restriction $x\ge 0$ is what you intented, otherwise I have to delete this part

Answer (score 1):

The second half: if $k < 0$ then $x^2 > k$ then $x^2 \ge 0$ is trivial and irrelevant as $x^2 \ge 0 > k$ is always true.

So a better statement is: for $k \ge 0$ is it true $x^2 > k \implies |x| > \sqrt{k}$.

The answer is yes.  If $|x| \le \sqrt{k}$ while $|x| \ge 0$ then $x^2 = |x||x| \le |x|\sqrt{k} \le \sqrt{k}\sqrt{k} = k$, which is a contradiction.